# How do I develop a software product with multiple dynamic sub-domains?

Tags: subdomain, web-applications

I am currently working on a twitter clone. How do I make it like Tumblr where a subdomain is created for each user that creates a blog? I would plan to show the user feed there, with posts from the users he follows.

Comment: You are looking for a "wildcard" subdomain entry in DNS.

Comment: Depending upon the web server, there may be limitations to how many sub-domains that can be hosted on a single machine. I am sure quite a few sub-domains can be hosted, however, if you plan to do this, you may be requiring another mechanism such as a proxy server. I would check to see if there is a limitation with your web server. As well, it is possible that configurations can load much slower as they grow. It all depends upon scale and how many users you intend to host. Just keep this in mind. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to setup your web server, using Apache as an example you would load your application to the default web root which would mean that all connections to the web server regardless of domain name would be handled by your application. The next step would be to configure your software to get the domain name from Apache (which depends on the language you are using and is a programming question not a webmaster question), then you would create a [wildcard DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) which points to your web server. At that point every single sub domain entry would be directed to your application. This has the benefit of not hitting any limits on DNS entries or Apache vhost configurations as there is only one vhost configuration in Apache (the default site) and only one DNS record (the wildcard dns record).